# SAP HANA SQL - Relative Date in Query

Tags: sql, tableau-api, hana

We are trying to build better dynamic reporting in our SQL queries from SAP HANA. Currently we either have to hard code the values, or we have a python tool which we update the values, but we are looking to point Tableau Server direct to SAP HANA and not have to go in and update the date ranges we are looking at.

We are looking to get a dynamic date selection for current and prior year where the structure is YYYYMMM in both the FROM and TO functions.

```
FROM "_SYS_BIC"."fvr.Revenue.FVRRsummary/ST_FVRR_COPA" ( 
'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_FROM_FISCAL_YR_PER$$', '2019001'),
'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_TO_FISCAL_YR_PER$$', '2020012')
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use external tool to update parameter's values, because HANA Calculation View has ability to calculate parameter's dafault value (e.g. when no external value passed to it from SQL/MDX).

You can use simple calculations to set default value for parameter in parameter definition screen. They can be based on constants, some other parameter's value or meta-information (like current date, logon language).

For your case you can use a parameter type *Direct* and set default values as follow:

- `IP_FROM_FISCAL_YR_PER`: `format(addmonths(now(), -12), 'yyyy"001"')`.
- `IP_TO_FISCAL_YR_PER`: `format(now(), 'yyyy"012"')`.

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

Use this sample query for HANA

-----*******
do begin
DECLARE DT TIMESTAMP;
DT:='2005-03-31';

SELECT  CASE WHEN (MONTH(:DT)) <= 3
THEN cast((YEAR(:DT))-1 AS varchar)     || '-' || RIGHT(cast((YEAR(:DT)) AS varchar)   ,2)
ELSE
cast((YEAR(:DT)) AS varchar)  || '-' || RIGHT(cast((YEAR(:DT)) AS varchar)   ,2)+1 END AS "FYear"
FROM "DUMMY";
END
;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).